# How can I keep a JFrame to specific width and height?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I made a 840 by 400 frame and added a text field. By default, the java app shrinked only to the size of the text field. I want it fixed to the respective size.

I tried `setResizable(false)`, `setExtendedState()`, `setBounds()` with no avail.

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling `pack()` somewhere?

Comment: I added the pack() line after all of the others. Why?

Comment: Calling `pack()` validates the entire frame component hierarchy and sets the size of the frame to the preferred size computed by the contained component. Either follow HFOE solution or don't call pack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 setPreferredSize(new Dimension(840,400));
```

If you named your frame you can do

```
 name.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(840,400));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. setSize() wouldn't work but setPreferredSize() did.

Comment: @user2320553 the use of setPreferredSize() is not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

Best to use a JPanel as your contentPane or add it to the contentPane, and to override its `getPreferredSize() method and then use`pack()` on the JFrame.  For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = 300;

   public MyPanel() {
      //...
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("My GUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(myPanel);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

One advantage of this is that other classes cannot change MyPanel's size via `setSize(...)` or `setPreferredSize(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I don't understand too much but I don't have to anyway for the time being.

Comment: The technical debt will accumulate interest; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).